# Chrome extensions keeps getting disabled

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have an own [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/psonopw-password-manager/eljmjmgjkbmpmfljlmklcfineebidmlo) and I currently face a weird problem.

Now and then (about daily) I recognize that my extension has been disabled. When I check, Chrome offers me the option to "repair" it, which works perfectly.

I started chrome in debug log and "identified" this passage, which is always the last one in the log before no further message of my extensions is recorded:

```
[10976:8112:0720/210546.491:WARNING:extension_protocols.cc(464)]
Failed to GetPathForExtension: eljmjmgjkbmpmfljlmklcfineebidmlo 
[10976:8112:0720/210546.491:WARNING:url_request_job_manager.cc(90)]
Failed to map: chrome-extension://eljmjmgjkbmpmfljlmklcfineebidmlo/data/fonts/opensans-vietnamese.woff2 
[14124:3076:0720/210546.494:VERBOSE1:script_context.cc(120)]
Destroyed context for extension   
extension id: eljmjmgjkbmpmfljlmklcfineebidmlo
effective extension id: eljmjmgjkbmpmfljlmklcfineebidmlo
```

I checked and `data/fonts/opensans-vietnamese.woff2` exists as it should.

Comment: Try https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging

Comment: Thanks, ill try it.

Comment: Found something, but I don't understand how it happens.